# Fedora 23, can't use high resolution on all displays anymore

Tags: linux, drivers, fedora, gpu, amd-radeon

So I'm having a strange issue here. I'm running Fedora 23, and after a package update, I'm no longer able to utilize high resolution on all 3 of my displays, only one of them. On my main display the resolution is 1600x900, but on the other two, identical displays, the resolution is capped at 1024x768. Previously I was able to set them all to 1600x900.

I'm using a VisionTek Radeon 1GB 5570 VHDCI B2 PCIe on Fedora 23. Is there something wrong with my graphics driver, caused by the update? I was jut using the basic opensource driver, I don't know what it's called or how to check for issues with it? My linux knowledge is strictly command line stuff, I usually just expect the GUI to work and don't worry otherwise haha. Thanks!

EDIT: xrandr output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3648 x 900, maximum 16384 x 16384
DisplayPort-0 connected 1024x768+2624+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      60.00* 
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   848x480       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
DisplayPort-1 connected 1024x768+1600+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      60.00* 
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   848x480       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
HDMI-0 connected primary 1600x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 434mm x 236mm
   1600x900      59.98*+
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.08    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    60.00  
   720x400       70.08  
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: It's most likely the graphics driver. Did you update the kenel or compile it manually? Do you use the driver from AMD or the new open source drivers (recommedet)?

Comment: Just updated it with dnf update. Figured it would be pretty harmless. :p I never installed a driver directly from AMD so I'm fairly certain I'm still using opensource drivers. How can I check them to make sure they're updated/installed properly? I don't know the name of it and googling is surprisingly unhelpful I'm finding.

Comment: What do you get from `xrandr` at the command line?

Comment: I added it to my post.